# What makes a great answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, faq-proposed

What does a great JL&U answer look like?

**Guidelines for answering this meta-question:**

- One quality per answer
- Provide a brief explanation of why it is important.
- Use the comments for discussion.
- If you don't agree, downvote the attribute. If you agree, upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provides credible sources if necessary**

- For very difficult questions, the answerer probably has to do some research before answering. Linking to these credible sources will increase the credibility of the answer.
- For answers that may be very surprising or unbelievable, it is probably best to provide a credible source so that the users do not think it it just your own crazy theory.

Answer (score 7):

**Formatting** is one important but often underrated aspect, I think. I feel much more attracted to read and upvote well-written and well-structured answers than others. Some points:

- Correct use of bold, italics, commas, etc.
- The answer is correctly divided in paragraphs in order to avoid the huge-wall-answer.
- Capitalization, capitalization, capitalization (answers starting with a lowercare letter, or the personal pronoun being written as "i").
- No abuse of horizontal lines (sometimes I see people using them a lot, not good).
- Correct use of Blockquote for quoting statements or pieces of text, and Code Sample for code or similar uses (linguistics interlinear glosses is one good example).
- No abuse of the titles as a bad replacement for the bold.

Answer (score 0):

(I think this is slightly different from what Alenanno meant with "correctly divided in paragraphs in order to avoid the huge-wall-answer", but if it is the same, I will gladly remove this answer)

**Clear and concise**

- Does not go on for multiple paragraphs unless those paragraphs truly add a lot of value
- Answer itself is obvious (you don't have to dig around for it)